# iOS app localization for a single Language

Tags: ios, localization

I look into every answers on stack overflow related to that argument but i can't find something useful for my situation, so i try to create a more specific question:

I have to create an application localized in **Italian Language only**, here my steps:

- Set `Italian` as default language in iTunes connect
- Set `Native development region` to Italy in the info plist (not sure it's useful...)
- Removed English from the project Localizations
- Added Italian in the project Localizations (screenshot below)

[image]

In my opinion this would be the correct way to set an Application for a single language (different by the Default English).

But looking into Target build phases I found that infoPlist.string is no more available: 
[image]

That is extremely strange because i can compile my project with no error...

At the end this procedure would results in filling "Language" property in iTunes app area with "Italian" and not with "English".

So, I wonder if my steps are correct or if I commit some errors. What do you think about this procedure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing a single-language app which only ever shows Italian, then you don't need localization at all. Just enter all your strings in Italian! It's still good practice to use a `localizable.strings` file and call `NSLocalizedString` instead of using hardcoded strings in your code so that you don't have to make code changes if one day you do decide to localize your app. But for now you can remove everything under Localizations in XCode and just make sure that the native region ([CFBundleDevelopmentRegion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1)) in your info.plist file is set to Italy. You'll probably find a setting in XCode that sets this for you if you root around the project's target settings.

Comment: so the CFBundleDevelopmentRegion is wired to the language that appears in iTunes ? And what about CFBundleLocalizations ? i'm really confused about these two fields at this point.

Comment: When you create a new app in iTunesConnect, one of the fields you need to select is the default language. This probably is what ends up as the language in iTunes, and I expect that your CFBundleDevelopmentRegion setting should match (I'm not sure though--I only ever left the default language as English). As for CFBundleLocalizations, it's the list of languages for which your app has localized resources. XCode automatically updates this when you click + or - under Languages. If you have no localization, I think CFBundleLocalizations can be left out entirely.

Comment: Even if I filled language field with Italian, iTunes still shows "English" :(  I tried a submission with the steps that I show in my question... as soon as i get the app on the store I write back in this post.